# How to write $P(\delta = 1 | X = x)$ as function of $P(\delta = 1 | X = x, Y = y)$

Tags: probability, random-variable, conditional-probability

Suppose that $\delta$ is a Bernoulli random variable, and suppose that $X, Y$ are continuous random variables. Is there a way to write $P(\delta = 1  | X = x)$ as function of $P(\delta = 1  | X = x, Y = y)$?

I know that from the law of total probability, for sets $A, B,$ and $C$, we have that $P(A|B) = P(A|B, C)P(C|B) + P(A|B, \bar{C})P(\bar{C}|B)$

However, since I'm dealing with random variables here, I'm not sure how to take the complement as I would for a set.

Comment: The involved events are $\{ \delta = 1 \} (= \{ \omega \mid \delta(\omega) = 1 \}$, a convention in prob theory), $\{ X = x \}$, and $\{ Y = y \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of events, when there are two possibilities and you can invert them and use the total probability law. In case of multiple values for the event, you'd have:
$$\sum_{C_i=\mathcal{S_c}} P(A|B,C_i)P(C_i|B)$$
Similarly, this could be used for discrete RVs w/o requiring much of a change. In continuous case, the summation converts into an integral and we need the knowledge of conditional density of $Y$ given $X$:
$$P(\delta=1|X=x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(\delta=1|X=x,Y=y)p_{Y|X}(y|x)dy$$

The integral can be narrowed down to the support of the conditional PDF, if known.

Answer (score 1):

From the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) you have:

$$\mathbb{P}(\delta = 1|X=x) = \int \limits_\mathscr{Y} \mathbb{P}(\delta = 1|X=x,Y=y) \ p(Y=y|X=x) \ dy.$$